# I need an API to plot waypoints and give me a route through them, and to give me city population. Which API should I use?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm making an iOS app that needs to be able to find the most populated cities within a radius from a certain point, and to calculate a route that passes through a certain number of those cities, that satisfy a certain time constraint. I'm planning to use Google to give me polylines that I can put directly on an Apple Map in the Mapkit for Xcode. I've looked into the Google Maps SDK for iOS, and Google Places. Google also has a Directions API, and a Distance Matrix API. With so many API's, I'm slightly confused about which one I should use, and for what.

Additionally, do Google API's provide city population, or should I find that via another database?

Comment: Have you tried to searching around over https://developers.google.com/ for population data? What all things you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) to get directions for Google Maps iOS.

If you are ever confused about which API to use for Google Maps, you can use [API picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker).

There is no Google API that give city population, so you would need to find it with a another database.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if the URL Scheme can give me polylines that I can use with another map, or will I need an actual Google Map in place in my app?

Comment: It looks like you need actual Google Maps,  ig you want for your own custom map, it might be better to use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Okay, looks like you can also use polyline objects that can be returned and used as an overlay on another map.